# An error occured while connecting to CRM server within my plug-in

Tags: plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Please help me figure out how to get ride of this error:

> ```
> An error occured while connecting to CRM server.
> ```

### My code

```
namespace AutoCreateAccountAndContactFromLead
{
public class CreateAccountAndContact : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Extract the tracing service for use in debuuging sandboxed plug-ins
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        // The InputParamaters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
        if(context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameter
            Entity lead = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            // If the entity's schema name is not "lead", then return. If it is, execute try block.

            if (lead.LogicalName != "lead")
                return;

            try
            {
                // check plug-in is registerd in pre-operational stage.
                if (context.Stage == 20)
                { 
                    // vars for create contact
                    var firstName = lead.Attributes["firstname"];
                    var lastName = lead.Attributes["lastname"];
                    var jobtitle = lead.Attributes["jobtitle"];
                    var emailaddress1 = lead.Attributes["emailaddress1"];
                    var mobilephone = lead.Attributes["mobilephone"];
                    var businessphone = lead.Attributes["telephone1"];

                    // vars for create account
                    var accountname = lead.Attributes["companyname"];
                    var websiteurl = lead.Attributes["websiteurl"];
                    var street1 = lead.Attributes["address1_line1"];
                    var street2 = lead.Attributes["address1_line2"];
                    var street3 = lead.Attributes["address1_line3"];
                    var city = lead.Attributes["address1_city"];
                    var stateprovice = lead.Attributes["address1_stateorprovince"];
                    var postalcode = lead.Attributes["address1_postalcode"];
                    var countryregion = lead.Attributes["address1_country"];

                    // create a contact entity
                    Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
                    contact["firstname"] = firstName;
                    contact["lastname"] = lastName;
                    contact["jobtitle"] = jobtitle;
                    contact["emailaddress1"] = emailaddress1;
                    contact["telephone1"] = businessphone;
                    contact["emailaddress1"] = emailaddress1;
                    contact["mobilephone"] = mobilephone;

                    // create an account entity
                    Entity account = new Entity("account");
                    account["name"] = accountname;
                    account["websiteurl"] = websiteurl;
                    account["address1_line1"] = street1;
                    account["address1_line2"] = street2;
                    account["address1_line3"] = street3;
                    account["address1_city"] = city;
                    account["address1_stateorprovince"] = stateprovice;
                    account["address1_postalcode"] = postalcode;
                    account["address1_country"] = countryregion;

                    // Obtain the orginxation service reference.
                    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                    // contact and account
                    service.Create(contact);
                    service.Create(account);
                }

            }
            catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured while connecting to CRM server.", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("FollowupPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have registered the above plug-in in the pre-operational stage. If the above code is able to create a contact and a account, how could I retrieve the contactId and accountId to link them together. i.e there is lookup field in account to link the related contact. Thanks.

Comment: service.Create will return a Guid which you can assign to a variable and use it later if you require them to update any other record further.
In your case it will be something like this
Guid contactId=service.Create(contact);
Use this contactId while creating the account entity object to fill that lookup field and create the account so in one single transaction it will be all done.

Comment: Hi Renjith, thanks for your advice. Do you know why Catch block throw that error with my code?

Comment: I have tested the code create contact and account separately, and I found that the error occurred while creating the account. Anyone know why?

Comment: that error is actually your custom text, anything coming out of "ex" ? can you do process of elimination like any other plugin account creation, remove certain attributes while creation, try registering plugin on post-create, etc